# LinkageError: Loader constraint violation when running junit test with hamcrest in pde enviornment

Tags: maven, osgi-bundle, eclipse-pde, hamcrest, linkageerror

I am trying to test a class using junit and hamcrest. here is the test that I have:

```
 @Test
public void testConvert()
{
    assertNull(converter.convert(null));
    assertNull(converter.convert(CommonentityFactory.eINSTANCE.createOrganization()));

    OrganizationMID organizationMID = OrganizationMID.create(DOMAIN, 1234L);
    String organizationName = "organizationName";

    com.demographics.app.commonentity.Organization fromOrganization = CommonentityFactory.eINSTANCE
            .createOrganization();
    fromOrganization.setMID(organizationMID);
    fromOrganization.setNameFormatted(organizationName);

    com.search.organization.ui.Organization organization = converter
            .convert(fromOrganization);
    assertThat(organization.getOrganizationMID(), is(organizationMID));
    assertThat(organization.getOrganizationName(), is(organizationName));
}
```

When I run the test as a pde test, I get,

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/hamcrest/Matcher"
```

Here are my imports:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
```

And I am using `org.junit v4.8.2-v370` , `mockito-core v1.8.5` and `org.hamcrest.osgi v1.1`

I am not sure what's wrong here, but I feel that I dont have the dependencies set up right in my pom. 
Can anyone help me in figuring this one out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation When trying to use Mockito Argument Matcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003797/java-lang-linkageerror-loader-constraint-violation-when-trying-to-use-mockito-a)

Comment: It does not matter how you put `org.junit` 4.8 on the classpath in an OSGi environment it will not work together with `mockito-core` (which depends on hamcrest).

Comment: @GáborBakos That question was posted by me. Your solution fixed the ArgumentMatcher issue I ran into but other parts of my tests started failing. I followed your advice and removed mockito-all and used mockito-core instead. Any idea what might be the problem here?

Comment: Still the org.junit 4.8. It cannot work well with hamcrest. :( Update it to at least 4.9.

Comment: I tried that too. I faced the same issue so I reverted back for consistency purpose as I am using junit v4.8 for non-pde tests.

Comment: I think in that case you should fix the other issues. Stock junit 4.8 (or the other bundle) will never work well in an OSGi environment when there are other bundles requiring hamcrest. All I can suggest is to update junit and try fix the other problems you mentioned. Using 4.8.x or before will not work without removing the org/hamcrest folder from the jar (and probably modifying the MANIFEST.MF file in the junit jar) - not recommended.

Comment: @GáborBakos I upgraded `org.junit` to `v1.3.0-SDK-4.4.2` and added `org.hamcrest.core v1.3.0-SDK-4.4.2` as the MANIFEST of org.junit has `Require-bundle org.hamcrest.core;bundle-version="1.3.0";visibility:=r
 eexport` in it. But now the problem is that I am not able to validate org.mockito.core, it says `missing constraint: Import-Package: org.hamcrest;version=[1.0.0-2.0.0]`. The MANIFEST of `org.hamcrest.core v1.3.0-SDK-4.4.2` says `Export-Package: org.hamcrest;version="1.3.0";core=split;mandatory:=cor
 e,`
I am assuming its not resolving cz of the split package thing. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry, I have never seen this `;core=split;mandatory:=core` syntax. In case the maven dependencies are not good for some reason, you might try eclipse orbit: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20150124073747/

Comment: I did some searching online and found this : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=403676
I guess there is no way to solve this without changing the MANIFEST